# How do I make the Mini Cooper (model 10242) motorized?

Tags: motor

I'm trying to find out what exact parts I need to make the Lego Mini Cooper 10242 motorized. I'm trying to surprise my boyfriend with the set plus the parts he needs to make it motorized. I'm just at a loss of finding what extra parts I need to buy so any help and advice is much appreciated! Thanks so much!

Comment: Welcome Danielle! The Mini Cooper is a static display model, unlike many Technic LEGO cars which have working steering and transmissions. You will need to make significant modifications to adjust the car enough to make it accept a working drive mechanism, including incorporating axles and gears, putting a motor and battery-box under the hood and other cosmetic and functional adjustments. Definitely not a simple "add a motor and it works" option. Also, this would not address steering - the model itself has no working steering mechanism. Net, a significant challenge - not impossible, just large.

Comment: There are lots of pictures and videos of people who have done this on the net, but I couldn't find anybody that had shared instructions or a part list.  You could get a kit that includes the motors and remote control and give him the challenge of merging them together.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the only example I can think of.

We can see an example in the following video @0:39 by *PPUNG DADDY*:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kvVJXhs_Q3s&t=38s

Here is the servo-motor:

[image]

And the IR receiver on the rear, next to one motor. The battery is located behind the driver's seat:

[image]

We have a better view at the end of the video: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kvVJXhs_Q3s&t=1m31s

---

In order to do the same build, you would need:

What we clearly see in the video:

- [Rechargeable Battery Box](http://brickset.com/sets/8878-1/Rechargeable-Battery-Box) (or the cheaper but bigger [Battery Box](http://brickset.com/sets/8881-1/Battery-Box))
- [Servo-Motor](http://brickset.com/sets/88004-1/Servo-Motor)
- [IR Receiver](http://brickset.com/sets/8884-1/IR-Receiver)
- [L-Motor](http://brickset.com/sets/88003-1/L-Motor)

What is not shown but necessary:

- a remote controller: [IR Remote Control](http://brickset.com/sets/8885-1/IR-Remote-Control) or [IR Speed Remote Control](http://brickset.com/sets/8879-1/IR-Speed-Remote-Control) (allow to control speed of the motors but it responds more slowly)
- mount front wheels on a steering: see the front of [this car](http://brickset.com/sets/8207-1/Dune-Duster) for example: there are some fixed and free parts
- mount rear wheels on rotating axis with a differential gear between the 2 wheels
- some gears in order to transfer the movements from motors to the wheels:

  - direction on the front wheels from the Servo-Motor (but there may be some simpler setups)
  - gears between the differential and the L-Motor

These pieces would cost between 80 to 100 $, € or £ (I used the Brickset's average prices).

---

I don't have this model so I can't tell you what exact parts are required, sorry.